# Why is my Javascript validation not working?

Tags: javascript, validation, getelementsbyname

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function formValidator(){
// Make quick references to our fields
var username = document.getElementByName('username');
var password = document.getElementByName('password');
var email = document.getElementByName('email');

// Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
    if(isAlphanumeric(username, "Please only use letters and numbers for you username.")){
        if(lengthRestriction(username, 8, 12)){
            if(lengthRestriction(password, 6, 15)){
                if(emailValidator(email, "Please enter a valid email address")){
                            return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


return false;
}


function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function lengthRestriction(elem, min, max){
var uInput = elem.value;
if(uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <= max){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Please enter between " +min+ " and " +max+ " characters");
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

My script isn't working, even though the username, password and email text boxes have defined the name attribute. Thanks :).

Comment: "Not working" is not a very helpful description of the problem.  Try adding some information about where it is going wrong and what messages you are seeing when you run the script.

Comment: But I am not receiving any error messages, and I have detailed the problem. The JavaScript validation is not validating..not working? What would be a better title?

Comment: Perhaps something like: "My JavaScript validation function does not prevent submission of invalid data", although the problem is most likely "My JavaScript validation function triggers syntax errors" ;-) Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Running this script in IE, for example, gives the message "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the first line.

Try to find out where it isn't working.  Turn on script debugging in your browser and trace the execution of the function - look at the values of the variables as you pass through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementByName` isn't a valid method for the `document` object.  You want `getElementsByName`, which will return a collection of elements with the specified `name` attribute, or `getElementById()` which will return a single element with the specified `id` attribute.

```
// get the first element with name="username"
var username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0];

// get the first element with name="password"
var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];

// get the first element with name="email"
var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0];
```

Comment: Alright. It is possible to use multiple classes on one class E.G. class="contact-input contact-left", right?

Comment: @Sam: yes.  In fact, it's the only way to apply multiple classes to a single element.

Answer (score 2):

There is no DOM method "getElementByName", you may wish to consider using `getElementById` or `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementByName('username'); return array or elements with name username... so add index too... ie document.getElementByName('username')[0];

it should be like:

```
var username = document.getElementByName('username')[0];
var password = document.getElementByName('password')[0];
var email = document.getElementByName('email')[0];
```

Comment: I've changed my code to..
     var username = document.getElementByName('username')[0];
 var password = document.getElementByName('password')[0];
 var email = document.getElementByName('email')[0];

is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `getElementsByName` (please note the missing ***s*** in your code) and, as the plural form suggests, it returns an array with all the matching elements. If you only have one item per name, you can simply fetch the first item from the array.

Now, this method returns the DOM node. If you don't know what a node is, just think of it as the HTML tag. You can't validate a tag, you need to extract its `value` attribute.

These changes would get reflected as follows (with no error checking):

```
var username = document.getElementByName('username')[0].value;
var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
```

Is suggest you find the JavaScript console of your browser so you can get notified about syntax errors or, even better, use Firefox + Firebug.